# Stop Reloading data when move into another navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

i have 5 Navigation , and every navigation have fragment tablayout with 3-5fragment , i can stop reloading data in tablayout fragment, but how to stop reloading data if im moving into another navigation ?
example : now im in Navigation A when Tablayout has 3 fragments(1,2,3) when im click another fragment its okay and if data already load, so they didnt load again. and when im move into Navigation B when TabLayout has 2 fragments(4,5) its okay data load because its firsttime click, but when im moving again into Navigation A data will reload again. how to stop reloading if data already reload?

Comment: Store data into Local SQlite db.

Comment: im using json btw data load from web server

Comment: Store your JSON values into DB

Comment: This is one of the solution. But may get better than this @F_X

Comment: actually can use if else? like if(data=load) then do not load again